# numbers in string come out as "not numbers" or fals - Python

Tags: python, string, list, key, digit

So, I have a list of strings in **python**, and I am trying to find which keys are numbers.
I am trying to use `list.[key].isdigit()` but it only works with `'0'`
For instance:

```
list = ['0', '0', '0', '0.450000000000000', '0', '0', '0', '0.550000000000000']
```

will only determine that `'0'` is a digit, but `'0.45'` and `'0.55'` are not.
How can I fix this problem?

Thank you very much

Comment: Check out this link - http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Determine_if_a_string_is_numeric#Python

Answer (score 1):

You can use Exception handling and a function:

```
>>> def is_num(x):
...     try :
...         float(x)
...         return True
...     except ValueError:
...         return False
...     
>>> lis = ['0', '0', '0', '0.450000000000000', '0', '0', '0', '0.550000000000000']
>>> for x in lis:
...     print is_num(x)
...     
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This copes when spaces and text are mixed:

```
import re

def ok(val):
    m = re.match('\s*\d+\.?\d*\s*', val)
    if m and m.group(0) == val:
        return True
    return False

list = ['0', '0.450000000000000', '0', '23x', ' 2.7 ', '2. 7', '1.2.3']

for val in list:
    print ok(val), val

# True 0
# True 0.450000000000000
# True 0
# False 23x
# True  2.7 
# False 2. 7
# False 1.2.3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace '.' with zeros and check if its numeric or not assuming you get only floats and ints in your list...

```
>>> a
['0', '0.45']
>>> for each in a:
...     repl = each.replace('.','0')
...     if repl.isdigit():
...             print each
...
0
0.45
```